# From panel data to cross-sectional data using averages

Tags: r

I am very new to R so I am not sure how basic my question is, but I am stuck at the following point.

I have data that has a panel structure, similar to this

```
Country   Year   Outcome   Country-characteristic

A         1990   10        40
A         1991   12        40
A         1992   14        40
B         1991   10        60
B         1992   12        60
```

For some reason I need to put this in a cross-sectional structure such I get averages over all years for each country, that is in the end, it should look like,

```
Country Outcome Country-Characteristic

A       12      40
B       11      60
```

Has anybody faced a similar problem? I was playing with lapply(table$country, table$outcome, mean) but that did not work as I wanted it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two tips: 1- When you ask a question, you should provide a reproducible example for the data too (as I did with `read.table` below). 2- It's not a good idea to use "-" in column names. You should use "_" instead.

You can get a summary using the `dplyr` package:

```
df1  <- read.table(text="Country   Year   Outcome   Countrycharacteristic
A         1990   10        40
A         1991   12        40
A         1992   14        40
B         1991   10        60
B         1992   12        60", header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
group_by(Country) %>%
summarize(Outcome=mean(Outcome),Countrycharacteristic=mean(Countrycharacteristic))

# A tibble: 2 x 3
  Country Outcome Countrycharacteristic
    <chr>   <dbl>                 <dbl>
1       A      12                    40
2       B      11                    60
```

Answer (score 0):

We can do this in `base R` with `aggregate`

```
aggregate(.~Country, df1[-2], mean)
#   Country Outcome Countrycharacteristic
#1       A      12                    40
#2       B      11                    60
```